# How to achieve sliding pages to left and right in HTML?

Tags: html, slideshow

How to achieve sliding pages to left and right in HTML (see [digerati](http://www.digerati.com.br/_digerati/) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html

and a page I developed with serial scroll / scroll to:

http://www.BeatTrainSoundSystem.com

You'll also need [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/